# Distribution of the product *not* independent Bernoulli distributed RV

Tags: statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two real valued stochastic variables , and assume that both are Bernoulli distributed
$$
P(X=1)=1-P(X=0)=p_1, \qquad P(Y=1)=1-P(Y=0)=p_2
$$
for $p_1,p_2\in(0,1)$. Note that we do **not** assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

> Show that the product $Z=XY$ is Bernoulli distributed.

Cleary $Z=1$ for $X=Y=1$ and $0$ if not. So
$$
f(Z)=\left\{
\begin{matrix}
p(X=1,Y=1) \text{ for } Z=1 \\
1-p(X=1,Y=1) \text{ for } Z=0
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$
Is this not correct? Can I express it better in terms of $p_1$ or $p_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every $\{0,1\}$-valued random variable is Bernoulli (this is the definition). If $X$ and $Y$ are $\{0,1\}$-valued, then $XY$ is $\{0,1\}$-valued and $[XY=1]=[X=Y=1]$ hence $XY$ is Bernoulli with parameter $P(X=Y=1)$.

In general, unless one assumes some further hypothesis such as the independence of $X$ and $Y$, one cannot deduce $z=P(X=Y=1)$ from $x=P(X=1)$ and $y=P(Y=1)$ but one always have $$\max\{0,x+y-1\}\leqslant z\leqslant\min\{x,y\}.$$

Comment: Is that not the same as I wrote?

Comment: Your questions are "Is this not correct? Can I express it better in terms of p1 or p2?" Does this answer these?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Just one more question. Can you point me in the direction on how to proof the inequality you wrote?

Comment: You are welcome. Surely you can prove at least one of these inequalities.

Comment: Is this correct: $z=P(X\mid Y)P(Y)\le P(Y)$ and $z=P(Y\mid X)P(X)\le P(X)$, so $z\le\min(x,y)$.

Comment: Yes, if one replaces every $X$ by $X=1$ and every $Y$ by $Y=1$ in your formula.

Comment: But do I not have to show it for all values of Y and X?

Comment: No--please come back to the *definitions* of $x$, $y$, $z$.

Comment: Arrgh! Brainfart :)

Answer (score 1):

What you did was correct. In fact, Z can take only 2 values: 0 and 1, so it has no option apart from being Bernoulli! However, the parameter of this Bernoulli distribution **cannot** be determined without any knowledge of the **joint distribution** of X and Y. Consider 2 cases: CASE-1: X = Y and p1 = p2 = p (say). Then Z follows Bernoulli(p). CASE-2: X and Y are independent, but both follow Bernoulli(p). Then Z follows Bernoulli(p^2).